# iPhone: is YAJL accepted for usage by the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, yajl

Does anyone know if using YAJL for JSON parsing on iOS is accepted by the AppStore?

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't block apps for using specific libraries unless they break the TOS. I have used YAJL in iPhone apps before without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be.  You need to link as a .a not .dylib or include the source in your app.

You might want to look at TouchJSON as well http://github.com/schwa/TouchJSON